# How do I diagnose input/output errors?

Tags: bash, file-io

I am totally baffled.  I used

```
su cp -a /my/home/dir /backup/home/dir
```

to backup my home directory and found a few files (about 20) that didn't copy due to input/output errors.  These files look fine, some are .jpgs, some are .gifs, one is my Virtualbox VDI file...they work fine on the original home dir, but they JUST WON'T COPY.  I tried manually doing them.  I tried doing them using Nautilus.  I tried changing the permissions to 777 and made sure the ownership was non-root...still no dice.  I get:

```
cp: reading `/my/home/dir/subfolder/abc_def.gif': Input/output error
```

I'm scratching my head and while I could lose a gif or jpg here and there, I don't want to lose my vdi file.  Do I need to add a --force to the cp command?  Is there any way to find out more info about why these particular files aren't copying?  In the case of the .jpgs, they're all in one folder of images I took during a recent trip, shot in the same camera, same CF card, and transferred the same way at the same time.

Totally baffled.  Any help would be fantastic.  Ideally, a way to force copy these files.  They seem to be fine, usable, and I trust them, so I've no clue why they're not getting copied.

Comment: Input/Output errors during filesystem access attempts generally mean hardware issues.

Comment: Yikes.  Okay.  Is there any good option for fixing/repairing?  Can I do anything on a per file basis?  I was able, with one of the gifs, to simply open the original and rename it, and save it on the new drive.  But I'm not sure how to do that with the VDI file.

Comment: Check your dmesg logs for errors. On what kind of filesystem you get that errors?

Comment: Try to run badblocks -nsv /dev/sdX to check for bad blocks.

Comment: It's a ext4 filesystem.  Somehow I thought ext4 didn't need fsck and so on, that this was done automatically at certain times.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldnt happen if you use ext4 because it uses journaling. My approach would be badblocks or fsck... Good luck^^

Comment: Well, I tried a different approach:  I went through each of the files and decided there's nothing I can't live without.  It's a cop out, I suppose, but really, it's just a few files...nothing vital.